# A simple way to simulate "survey data" with a specified mean and range, or two samples of whole numbers with a standardised mean difference

Tags: r, simulation

I want to simulate survey data- think of a survey where people respond on a scale from 1(strongly disagree) to 7(strongly agree).

I want to be able to specify the mean of the simulated sample, as well. For example, I want to simulate 100 numbers between 1 and 7 with a mean of 4 and an SD of 1.

Then I would like to simulate 100 more numbers between 1 and 7 with a mean of 3 and an SD of 1.

This way, I can compute an effect size of d = 1.00. I will use this data for a classroom demonstration.

`rnorm()` allows me to specify a mean, but not the bounds.

`runif()` allows me to specify the bounds but not the mean.

`sample()` allows me to specify the bounds but not the mean.

Applying `round()` to `rnorm()` gives me whole numbers, but will sometimes generate 0s or 8s (eg numbers outside of the 1-7 range). Yes, I can recode them but this adjusts my effect size:

```
round(rnorm(200, 2, 1))
```

Is there not a way to generate either
whole numbers between 1 and 7 with a specified mean
OR
two samples with a specified mean difference and range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about rounding the result of `truncnorm::truncnorm()`?

```
library(truncnorm)
set.seed(1234)
u <- round(rtruncnorm(10000, a=1, b=7, mean=3, sd=1))
summary(u)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   3.000   3.054   4.000   7.000
```

Comment: Ah, that works pretty well! I have never come across that function or package before. This is a very simple solution to a problem that so many people have. Thanks!